# Flutter Getx , Wait till all main binding load before Navigation

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using getx on my project, I have a mainBianding page :

```
class MainBinding implements Bindings {
  @override
  Future<void> dependencies() async {
    Get.putAsync<HiveService>(() => HiveService().init(), permanent: true);
    Get.lazyPut<HomeController>(
      () => HomeController(

          dbclient: Get.find<HiveService>()),
    );
  }
}
```

I have a GETXService for initializing Hive

```
class HiveService extends GetxService {
  late Box<Model> vBox;

  Future<HiveService> init() async {
    final appDocumentDirectory =
        await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive
      ..init(appDocumentDirectory.path)
      ..registerAdapter<Model>(ModelAdaptor())

    return this;
  }
```

After lunching App HomePage and HomeController will be launched but I got this error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following message was thrown building Builder:
"HiveService" not found. You need to call "Get.put(HiveService())" or
"Get.lazyPut(()=>HiveService())"
The relevant error-causing widget was:
  ScrollConfiguration
```

because Hive service is a future Is has a delay to be loaded but I used `Future<void> dependencies() async` on this binding class. How do I have to wait to be sure HiveService load completely and after that Home Page load?
I am using MainBinding Inside `GetMaterialApp`;

```
    Future main() async {
      await MainBinding().dependencies();
    ...

  runApp(MyApp()
    return GetMaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
      locale: DevicePreview.locale(context),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      initialRoute: Routes.HOME,
      getPages: AppPages.pages,
      initialBinding: MainBinding(),
```

Comment: You are not awaiting `Get.putAsync(...)`, try `await Get.putAsync(...)`. Without the `await` keyword, the future is created and the operation is run, but the code continues to execute before the result is returned.

Comment: Here it the complete example of nested controllers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75497500/16194683

Comment: Here is the complete example of nested controllers https://stackoverflow.com/a/75497500/16194683

Comment: Here is the complete example of nested controllers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75497500/16194683

Answer (score 8, accepted):

test this

```
await Get.putAsync<HiveService>(() => HiveService().init(), permanent: true);
```

Comment: This helped. I was missing the "await" at the beginning. 

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your service.init() function first. and then return the getx Service(HiveService) and complete to load this service to the memory.

```
  @override
  Future<void> dependencies() async {
    await Get.putAsync< HiveService >(() async {
      final HiveService service = HiveService();
      await service.init();
      return service;
    });
    Get.lazyPut<HomeController>(
      () => HomeController(

          dbclient: Get.find<HiveService>()),
    );
  }
}
```